# Deserialize nested json to string property

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I have a json file that contains nested json which I would like to deserialize into a string property upon configuration binding.

This is the configuration file:

```
{
  "Service": {
    "Id": "ccApiMicroservice",
    "Configuration": {
      "Option1": "value1",
      "Option1": "value2"
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the corresponding configuration class:

```
public class ServiceOptions
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringConverter))]
    public string Configuration { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried to use a custom json converter to convert the nested json to string, however the converter is ignored by the binding mechanism (have breakpoints in the converter's methods, but not one is hit), even though I have configured it in the ConfigureServices like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(
            options => options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new JsonStringConverter()));

    services.Configure<ServiceOptions>(this.Configuration.GetSection("Service"));
}
```

What am I missing? Why is the converter ignored? Or is there another way how can I deserialize the nested json to string property?

**Edit**

The reason why I tried to use a custom JSON converter is that if I try to access the `ServiceOptions` instance anywhere in the application I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot create instance of type 'System.String' because it is missing a public parameterless constructor.'
```

Comment: I am of course using Newtonsoft JSON as it is a default serializer used by ASP .NET core. The problem is that if I bind the `ServiceOptions` configuration class to JSON using this line: `services.Configure<ServiceOptions>(this.Configuration.GetSection("Service"));`
 I get the following exception: 
`System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot create instance of type 'System.String' because it is missing a public parameterless constructor.'`. That is why I have tried to use a custom JSONConverter. However the convertor is ignored and I still get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a possibly easier way for you to get and parse your json items:

```
JObject config = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("config.json"));
string service_id = (string)config.SelectToken("Service").SelectToken("Id");
Console.WriteLine(service_id);
```